# Do secret doors exist (like in Diablo)?

Tags: path-of-exile

I wonder if Path of Exile has the same feature as Diablo: clicking walls and hoping to find a secret door. Does that exist?

Comment: Was that in diablo 1? in 2 it was not possible ;)

Comment: It is still possible in D2.

Comment: no it's not. what are you talking about man  ? you live in another world. i played d2 for 7 years and i can tell you every item stats possible but there are no hidden doors.

Comment: @RayofCommand There *ARE* hidden rooms in diablo 2, try clicking the middle of every wall of inaccessible areas completely surrounded by rooms in cathedral or jail levels.

Comment: okay i guess i learned something today. damn how could that be possible.

Comment: Wow makes me want to go back and play D2 now.  I did not know either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a player with a couple hundred hours under my belt and many more hours watching streams from many of the top players, I have never seen or heard of a secret door.

Short answer: Not likely, although there have been several suggestions for their inclusion.

Comment: Updating: Path of Exile Ascendancy, to be released March 4th, 2016, will include hidden doors in the Labyrinth.

Comment: @svavil I don't play PoE anymore. Feel free to update this answer with any relevant information.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, there are a bunch in the Labyrinth.